# How did a normal user self-delete a question with answers?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I recently got a notification for a comment on my answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202006/how-do-i-retract-my-review-vote) (10k only). However, when I got there, it was deleted. It was *self* deleted.

How did the user do it? When I try to delete a question of mine with answers, I get this:

[image]

What gives?

Comment: The bug is in the wording of the error message, should be "...has **upvoted** answers..." or to be more accurate "...has answers with positive score..."

Comment: *deleting a question with answers & upvotes* :( "Hey, please help me" - "sure, took me 15 mins to read your specific code, think a bit and write a really good reply with code examples, but here's some help" - "ok thanks, I'll delete this question now and remove your rep, hard work and negate any time and care you spent for me" :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can delete your own questions if they don't contain answers **with a positive net score**.